# android onActivityResult socket timeout

Tags: android, sockets, android-intent, timeout

When I try to start a socket from onActivityResult it always times out... What I was trying to do was start the Activity that starts the socket connection from onActivityResult with no success, however when the sockets have no problem starting from somewhere else not called from onActivityResult. This is the code where I call startActivityForResult and the onActivityResult. I am pretty sure I am doing this wrong...any push in the right direction??

```
public void scanNow(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.blah.Blah.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("com.blah.Blah.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        Log.d("debug tag", "started activity");

    }
    @Override 
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
       Log.d("debug tag", "inside onActivityResult");
        if (requestCode == 0)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Log.i("debug tag", "contents: "+contents+" format: "+format);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(com.blah.Blah.Ads);
                startActivity(myIntent);

                // Handle successful scan
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                // Handle cancel
                Log.i("debug tag", "Cancelled from main");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You say, that you get a timeout, but you're only showing us the onActivityResult method - the onActivityResult method can't create a timeout for your socket connection - it has to be something in how you create the connection. Please post the code where you try to create the connection.

Comment: to keep from posting a whole bunch of code, if you replace Intent myIntent = new Intent(com.blah.Blah.Ads);
                startActivity(myIntent);    with Socket socket = new Socket("ipaddr",port);  you get a socket timeout, obviously that would be wrapped in try catch

Comment: Nothing is obvious, when you get an exception ;-)
Please modify the code, so it reflects what you're trying to do - this way the code can also be run by others and tested that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post the actual code that doesn't work maybe someone can help you better.
What is "somewhere else" where connection works? Did you try it in the same device, application, activity? Is the code exactly the same in both places?

Check these:

- You have internet permission in the manifest
- The actual networking call is not in the main thread